# PHP: I can not see the contents of $ _FILES when uploading images

Tags: php

The environment is MAMP, PHP version is 7.1.19.
We are assuming a contact form on the landing page that we do not use framework etc.

- Because the code is long, the part which does not correspond to the question content is deleted

Below, select an image in form.html, push "submit" to "Confirmation screen", then display the image data in $ _FILES in the log to add the code of the image upload processing in confirm.php I want to.

However, even if you try to display the contents of $ _FILES in the log file with error_log ('confirm-files:'. Print_r ($ _ FILES, true), '0'); Array () I can not see the contents. By the way, file name is displayed in $ _POST.

Please tell us why the contents of $ _ FILES can not be seen.

After that, save the database as a tmp file on the server without using the database, after the transition to thanks.php, we will add the process to register to the customer management system.
Thank you.

・contact form

```
<form method="post" action="<?=$sfm_script?>" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="file">
     <label for="file1">Select files
         <input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" onchange="$('.file_name1').text($(this).val())" class="file_name1"></label><span class="file_name1">

  </div>
 <button type="submit">To confirmation screen</button>
 <input type="hidden" name="mailToNum" id="mailToNum" value="3">
 <input type="hidden" name="autoReply" id="autoReply" value="1"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="mode" id="mode" value="CONFIRM">
<?php if (array_key_exists('pram', $formvalue)):?>
 <input type="hidden" name="pram" id="pram" value="<?=$formvalue['pram']?>">
<?php else:?>
 <input type="hidden" name="pram" id="pram" value="">
<?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

・confirm.php

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8") ?>
<?php

include_once('config.php');

if (!extension_loaded('mbstring')) {
    Err('mbstring');
}
$internalEnc = 'UTF-8';
mb_language('ja');
mb_internal_encoding($internalEnc);

// main
if (!isset($mailTo[0])) {
    Err('mailaddress');
}
$mode = (isset($_POST['mode'])) ? $_POST['mode'] : '';

error_log ('confirm-files:' . print_r($_FILES,true), '0');

switch ($mode) {
case 'SEND': 
    session_cache_limiter('nocache');
    session_start();

//Om

    include_once('thanks.html'); 
    break;

case 'CONFIRM': 
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] && $refCheck) {
        Err('It can not be used from outside');
    }
    session_cache_limiter('nocache');
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['SFM']);

    $error = $email = '';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = implode("\t", $value);
        }
        if (!$ill_slash) {
            $value = (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? addslashes($value) : $value;
        }
        if (!$ill_char) {
            $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, $internalEnc, $baseEnc);
        }
        $value = mb_convert_kana($value, 'KV', $internalEnc);
        $name = preg_replace('/(.+)_i$/', "$1", $key);
        if (preg_match('/_i$/', $key) && $value == '') {
            $_SESSION['SFM'][$name] = '::INPUT ERROR::';
            $error = 1;
        } elseif ($name == 'email' && $value) {
            if (!preg_match("/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[\w\-\.]+\.([a-z]+)$/", $value)) {
                $_SESSION['SFM']['email'] = '::EMAIL ERROR::';
                $error = $email = 1;
            } else {
                $_SESSION['SFM']['email'] = $email = $value;
            }
        } elseif ($name == 'emailcheck') {
            if ($email != 1 && $email != $value) {
                $_SESSION['SFM']['email'] = '::EMAIL CHECK ERROR::';
                $error = 1;
            }
        } elseif ($maxText && strlen($value) > $maxText) {
            $_SESSION['SFM'][$name] = '::MAXTEXT ERROR::';
            $error = 1;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['SFM'][$name] = $value;
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['SFM']['InputErr'] = $error;
    //$sfm_script = $script_name . ((SID) ? '?'.strip_tags(SID) : '');
    $sfm_script = "thanks.php";
    include_once('confirm.html');
    break;
default:
    session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['SFM']);
    //$sfm_script = $script_name;
    $sfm_script = "confirm.php";
    include_once('form.html');
}
exit;

function FORM_DATA_H($name) {
    $errArray = array(
        '::INPUT ERROR::' => '<span class="req">Required</span>',
        '::EMAIL ERROR::' => 'E-mail address is invalid',
        '::EMAIL CHECK ERROR::' => 'Mail address does not match',
        '::MAXTEXT ERROR::' => 'Too many characters (upper limit ' . number_format($GLOBALS['maxText']) . '）'
    );
    $value = (isset($_SESSION['SFM'][$name])) ? $_SESSION['SFM'][$name] : '';
    $value = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? stripslashes($value) : $value;
    $value = str_replace("\t", "\n", $value); 
    $value = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $value = (preg_match('/::.+::/', $value)) ? '<span class="ERR">' . $errArray[$value] . '</span>' : $value;
    $value = ($value != '') ? $value : '&nbsp;';
    return mb_convert_encoding($value, $GLOBALS['baseEnc'], $GLOBALS['internalEnc']);
}

?>
```

・＄_FILES log

```
[10-Mar-2019 09:15:55 Asia/Tokyo] files:Array
(
)
```

・Upload process I want to add in the future

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $file) {
    if ($file['size'] > 0) {
        $time = strtotime('today');
        if (!file_exists('./files/' . $time)) {
            mkdir('./files/' . $time);
            chmod('./files/' . $time, 0777);
        }
        $tmp_name = str_replace('/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php', '', $file['tmp_name']);
        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], './files/' . $time . $tmp_name);
        $_FILES[$key]['tmp_name'] = './files/' . $time . $tmp_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is very well documented and, if I bothered to look for an instance your question should be closed as a duplicate of the many times this has been asked and answered here. You haven't set the form encoding so it is defaulting to URL encoding.

It should be `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I certainly forgotten enctype = "multipart / form-data".
However, $ _FILES is still not displayed, but are there other concerns?

Comment: Yes. Start by looking at some of the answers when other people have posted this question and learn how to write minimal, complete and verifiable code